# phonegap setinterval contiues after resume

Tags: javascript, cordova

If I use in phonegap

```
 setInterval(func,20000);
```

I understand that this code does not run while the app in sleep. but when it resume the interval continue? or I have to set the interval again?

Comment: do it stop when app sleeps? I'm not sure that

Comment: if I want to create something that dont stop when the app sleep I have to create background service.. phonegap dont create this service  so it must stop.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the OS (Android, IOS, WindowsPhone, Blackberry) and the version of the OS, and how long the app is sleeping for.  In short, don't expect it to come back, and plan that it won't.  If you want to write a background service, look at something like [cordova-plugin-background](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode), it may not be 100% perfect but it is certainly a lot more reliable than setInterval...

Comment: I dont want to write background service. I want that the interval will not run in sleep. but I wanted to know if it continue to run when the app resume.
I think that I will disable this when the app going to sleep and on resume I will set it again

Comment: That would be the correct course of action.  Be aware that on Android your entire app may be destroyed and recreated depending on your setting of AndrdoidLaunchMode in the config.xml.  You probably want to set it to "<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />"